# See statements as Groovy scripts executes

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to see the statements of Groovy script as it executes, like the output of running bash with -v or -ex? What would it take to do this programmatically?

Comment: What you're talking about bears resemblance to a quine, which is far easier said than done.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to see the statements of Groovy script as it executes, like the output of running bash with -v or -ex?

I suppose it's possible, but I'm not aware of any tool that does this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done relatively easily using a global AST transformation whose `public void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit)` method adds println `Statement`s after or before each `Statement` visted in a class.

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Global+AST+Transformations for more details.